# CStdioFile.open Change the path to the file Runtime error?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mfc

What if I change the path to the file Runtime error?

1.

```
CStdioFile file;    
file.Open(_T("‏‏hb_n.txt"), CFile::modeRead | CFile::typeUnicode);
file.Close();
```

to work

To another file

2.

```
CStdioFile file;    
file.Open(_T("‏‏hb_n_2.txt"), CFile::modeRead | CFile::typeUnicode);
file.Close();
```

Not working - Runtime error?

Comment: ובכן hbn.txt רק אם אני לשנות את שם הקובץ m hbn.txt ל hbn2.txt לא עובד שגיאת זמן ריצה בכל פעם שאני אוהב את הקובץ שם הקובץ. If I don't change the filename does

Comment: Also file.Close() doesn't work

Comment: Probably the file isn't there. Change to `if (!file.Open(L"‏‏hb_n_2.txt", CFile::modeRead | CFile::typeUnicode) { DWORD error = GetLastError(); TRACE(L"%d\n", error); AfxMessageBox(L"stop"); }`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani It is not documented that `CStdioFile::Open()` sets the last error value. The proper way of retrieving the error code: `CFileException e; if( !file.Open(L"‏‏hb_n_2.txt", CFile::modeRead | CFile::typeUnicode, &e){TRACE(L"%d\n", e.m_lOsError);}`. Though I would prefer to use the constructor with a try/catch block to catch the `CFileException`.

Comment: @zett42 The main issue is testing for `CStdioFile::Open` success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine the cause of the error, use the constructor that throws a `CFileException` and use a try/catch block to handle that exception.

```
try
{
    CStdioFile file( _T("hb_n_2.txt"), CFile::modeRead | CFile::typeUnicode );
}
catch( CFileException* e )
{
    TRACE( L"Error code: %d\n", e->m_lOsError );
    e->ReportError();
    e->Delete();
}
```

`CFileException::ReportError()` shows the system error message. The `TRACE` call logs the error code in the debug output. You can lookup the [error code in the reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx) to get additional information.

Note that it is not required to explicitly call `CStdioFile::Close()` as the destructor of `CStdioFile` will do it automatically.

Also it is recommended to always use absolute file paths instead of relative paths. Relative paths depend on the current directory which often is not what you expect (code that is not under your control could change it at any time).